# Unable to get the first day of the Month in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm calculating the dates for my application like date,week,month.

First I am defining day,week,month,custom like:

```
this.reportTypes = [{TypeId: 1, Type: 'Day'}, {TypeId: 6, Type: 'Week'}, {TypeId: 30, Type: 'Month'}, {
      TypeId: 10,
      Type: 'Custom'
    }]
```

Next I'm defining dates like:

```
var currdate = new Date();
 if(reportType==1){
        // this.reportDataFromDate=currdate;
        // this.reportDataToDate=currdate;
        //This is for setting the current date
        this.reportDataFromDate= currdate;
        this.reportDataToDate= currdate;
    }
    else if(reportType==30){
      var First = new Date(currdate.getFullYear(),currdate.getMonth(),1);

      this.reportDataFromDate=First;

      this.reportDataToDate=currdate;
    }
    else if(reportType!=10){
       var last = new Date(currdate.getTime() - (reportType * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

      this.reportDataFromDate=last;
      this.reportDataToDate=currdate;
    }
  }
```

The problem is after selecting `reportType == 30` then it has to get the first day of the month.

It is showing the date as `1-Dec-2017` but it is getting the data of till 30th November 2017?

This is screenshot of the SQL server. I'm sending the date as 1st Dec 2017 but it is getting  30-11-2017.
[image]

Comment: what timezone are you in ... dont' forget, what you see in the console is UTC

Comment: @JaromandaX in the console im seeing the dec 1 2017 IST

Comment: indeed, sorry, what you show in the image is UTC (thought that was some console output) - so, it's all good

Comment: @JaromandaX it the data /request received  by back end..

Comment: whatever it is, it is 1 dec 2017 0:0:0 in your timezone

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel to find the first day of the month? Why not using a library to do so, like https://date-fns.org/docs/startOfMonth or momentjs?

Comment: @JaromandaX  yeah just like it is displaying and actually getting result too but getting from 30th Nov not from 1st Dec

Comment: @ David Dal Busco we are not recommended to use libraries for date so thats why

Comment: Are you using .Net WebApi to send the data to backend?

Comment: @SamuelShyu Yes

Comment: If you are doing any sort of calculations with dates, you should for sure look into something like moment.js as dates are WAY more complex than you may first think. Remember that the Date() object handles time with precision in milliseconds including a timezone offset, which you may or may not have given and may have been taken from the system. If you are just dealing with days this may become more of a burden than help.

Comment: @jornare  yeah i applied moment.js works like charm.. still i dont understand why the above code didnt worked..

Comment: @madpop Check out this talk for a deeper understanding https://youtu.be/acIOV8wtkOo?t=53m25s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why the difference?

The `new Date(x,y,z)` constructor treats the parameters as ***local date values***.

See [MDB Web Docs - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments.

But, under the hood the date is stored as UTC (milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970).

```js
const date = new Date(2017, 11, 29); 
console.log('valueOf()', date.valueOf())  // 1514458800000
```

and the UTC date is different to your local date (see trailing 'Z' indicates UTC)

```js
const date = new Date(2017, 11, 29); 
console.log('date', date)  // "2017-12-28T11:00:00.000Z" (trailing 'Z' means UTC)

// The difference in minutes between browser local and UTC
console.log('getTimezoneOffset()', date.getTimezoneOffset() )
```

and when you send it to the server, JSON sends it as UTC

```js
const date = new Date(2017, 11, 29); 
console.log('JSON', date.toJSON())
// JSON will yield string version of UTC === 2017-12-28T11:00:00.000Z
```

### How to fix it

Well, you might decide that you actually want the date/time in local, and conclude it's not broken.

But if you want to ***send*** UTC to the server, wrap the parameters in `Date.UTC()`

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC( 2017, 11, 29 ))
console.log('date.toJSON()', date.toJSON() )   // 2017-12-29T00:00:00.000Z
```

### What about month parameter === 11?

From the MDB page referenced above,

> Note: The argument month is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.

Answer (score 3):

When the Date() constructor is invoked with integers, the result is a date object with that date assumed your systems (read browser/os) timezone.

Example:

```
let d = new Date(2017);
// returns Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:02 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
// and with d.toUTCString(): Fri, 30 Dec 2016 23:00:00 GMT
```

Which may end up in an entire different year when sending to the server

Using the string constructor and specifying timezone will help you overcome this.

Example:

```
let d = new Date('2017z');
// returns Sun Jan 01 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
// and with d.toUTCString(): Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 GMT
```

The latter which is what you should pass to a server, and normally do calculations on.

However, note that calculations with dates are a complicated matter best left to a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). To get a feel of what you are dealing with have a look at this [great talk](https://youtu.be/acIOV8wtkOo?t=53m25s) from the WebRebel conference.

So to actually give an answer to your title, try this example which creates the date in a simple string using UTC:

```
let d = new Date(currdate.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' +(currdate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + ' 1z');
d.getUTCDay(); // returns the day as an integer where Monday is 0.
```

Note that we add 1 month due to getUTCMonth() returns January as 0.

Comment: Ok, sorry I just realized you already said the first part of my answer (perhaps not as well :) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net Web API as backend, you can config the timezone in Web API WebApiconfig.cs like below. It will serialize the time in UTC.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
}
```

Or use

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZ‌​oneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind; //Time zone information should be preserved when converting.
```